# My iPad unable to view subtitles

Tags: macbook-pro, ipad, subtitle

My iPad unable to open or view video online with subtitles. But when I open the same website with my lappy, the video and subtitles work well. There have something wrong with the website or my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Launch the Settings app on your iPhone or iPad.
2. Tap on General.
3. Tap on Accessibility.
4. Under the Hearing section, tap on Subtitles & Captioning.
5. Turn On the option for Closed Captions + SDH.
6. Tap on Style in order to customize how closed captions work if you'd like.

Also, what app/website are you viewing this in?

Source(s):

- Google (googled "subtitles on iPad")
- http://www.imore.com/how-enable-subtitles-and-captioning-auditory-accessibility-iphone-or-ipad